# Concat a List of Strings with additional Strings in between

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Here is what I'm searching for. I want to concat a given list for example:

```
list = [a,b,c,d]
```

and I want to concat those Strings. In between the concatination I want to put allways the same String so that the result looks like:

```
"Hey a, Hey b, Hey c, Hey d"
```

Is this possible in swi-Prolog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not only want to have "additional strings in between", since you also want something "in front" of each string.
More specifically, you want "Hey " in front of each String, and ", " between each of them.

I would use [`maplist/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/3) to concat the String "Hey " in front of each of your entries using [`atom_concat/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_concat/3).

All "Hey X"-entries can then be concatenated to a single string using [`atomic_list_concat/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/3).
This predicate also takes a separator which should be placed between all entries, i.e., ", " in your case.

```
List = [a,b,c,d], 
maplist(atom_concat("Hey "), List, HeyList), 
atomic_list_concat(HeyList, ", ", FinalString).
```

Result:

```
List = [a, b, c, d],
HeyList = ['Hey a', 'Hey b', 'Hey c', 'Hey d'],
FinalString = 'Hey a, Hey b, Hey c, Hey d'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an "intersperse" or "join" function, which is hidden behind the `atomic_list_concat/3` predicate:

[`atomic_list_concat/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/3)

`atomic_list_concat(+List, +Separator, -Atom)`

or alternatively to create SWI-Prolog "strings" (which are supposed to be used in scenarios where you process text):

[`atomics_to_string/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomics_to_string/3)

`atomics_to_string(+List, +Separator, -String)`